# Scala spark thorws ArrayOutOfBound exception on count,show function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dataset

I am running the following code in scala spark, whenever I hit an action function like count() or show I get the array out of bounds exception. I am able to print the schema though

```
val wordsDF = spark.read.format("bigquery")
            .option("table","bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare")
      .load()
      .cache()

    wordsDF.printSchema()
    wordsDF.count()
    wordsDF.show()
```

Error stack trace

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   10582     at
>   com.thoughtworks.paranamer.BytecodeReadingParanamer$ClassReader.accept(BytecodeReadingParanamer.java:563)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.paranamer.BytecodeReadingParanamer$ClassReader.access$200(BytecodeReadingParanamer.java:338)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.paranamer.BytecodeReadingParanamer.lookupParameterNames(BytecodeReadingParanamer.java:103)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.paranamer.CachingParanamer.lookupParameterNames(CachingParanamer.java:90)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$.getCtorParams(BeanIntrospector.scala:44)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$.$anonfun$apply$1(BeanIntrospector.scala:58)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$.$anonfun$apply$1$adapted(BeanIntrospector.scala:58)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:240)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:937)    at
>   scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:937)    at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1425)    at
>   scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:70)  at
>   scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:69)     at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)  at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:240)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:237)
>     at
>   scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$.findConstructorParam$1(BeanIntrospector.scala:58)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$.$anonfun$apply$19(BeanIntrospector.scala:176)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:233)
>     at
>   scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:32)
>     at
>   scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:29)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:194)
>     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:233)
>     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:226)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:194)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$.$anonfun$apply$14(BeanIntrospector.scala:170)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$.$anonfun$apply$14$adapted(BeanIntrospector.scala:169)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:240)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:388)  at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:240)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:237)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:351)  at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$.apply(BeanIntrospector.scala:169)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.ScalaAnnotationIntrospector$._descriptorFor(ScalaAnnotationIntrospectorModule.scala:22)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.ScalaAnnotationIntrospector$.fieldName(ScalaAnnotationIntrospectorModule.scala:30)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.ScalaAnnotationIntrospector$.findImplicitPropertyName(ScalaAnnotationIntrospectorModule.scala:78)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationIntrospectorPair.findImplicitPropertyName(AnnotationIntrospectorPair.java:467)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._addFields(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:351)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.collectAll(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:283)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getJsonValueMethod(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:169)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription.findJsonValueMethod(BasicBeanDescription.java:223)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BasicSerializerFactory.findSerializerByAnnotations(BasicSerializerFactory.java:348)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory._createSerializer2(BeanSerializerFactory.java:210)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:153)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1203)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:481)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findTypedValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:679)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:107)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3559)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:2927)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope.toJson(RDDOperationScope.scala:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:247)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:296)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$count$1(Dataset.scala:2831)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$count$1$adapted(Dataset.scala:2830)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$2(Dataset.scala:3365)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:78)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3365)  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.count(Dataset.scala:2830)    at
>   Transform$.main(Transform.scala:29)   at
>   Transform.main(Transform.scala)

Spark dependency used

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Trying to figure out what would be the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it by updating the spark version to 2.4.5, and protobuf-java version to 3.11.4.